# How to fix the 'send from' when using the Action pull-down to "Send Now"

Tags: email

When doing a search and then using the "Action" pull-down to select "Send Now" the from address displays as several lines of code. See image attached. How do you fix this? How do you cause this screen to display properly. This does not happen when using CiviMail or when sending individual emails.

[image: problem with from address]

Comment: can you replicate this on the Demo Site?

Comment: No, this does not happen on the demo site.

Comment: does that give you any clues then? ie something on yours has some special sauce that is affecting this

Comment: Yes it does. Any idea how to track down the problem?